# using javascript make button or link visible only on function call

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a button or link to appear on browser pop up window that makes a servlet request to get data. But the javascript that handles this should when an error occurs show the link or button on that window. Otherwise remain hidden.

```
 function showErrorOnStart()
    {
    document.getElementById("video").innerHTML = "<p>This file is of 
         unsupported type. Please download the file</p>";
    aud.style.visibility = "hidden";
    vid.style.display = "none";

    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("buttonLink");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
   }
   }


    <button id="buttonLink" type="button" 
         style="display:none;" onclick="myFunction()">DownLoad</button>
```

I have no idea what I'm doing and would like someone to guide me to get this done correctly. Basically this function is called when an error occurs and displays a suitable message, but this time I want to include a link/button that this window will display which a user can then click and it will return a video stream.

Comment: This question is really bad formatted. Keep an eye on details, like the braces you left outside. Keeping an eye on small details is a MUST when programming. A simple character can lead you crazy. Maybe you should read more or write more or reread more times what you write, but do it if you don't want to have all the problems you are having all these 8 years you are registered in StackOverflow.

Comment: yes; sorry about that, should know better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROTIP:** As I always say to newbies, indentation is a must. Your code is bad indented and things like that can lead to code misunderstanding, hence to errors.

As far as I can tell, you code is fine BUT when I clean your indentation, you have one function defined inside another function:

```
function showErrorOnStart() {
    document.getElementById("video").innerHTML = "<p>This file is of unsupported type. Please download the file</p>";
    aud.style.visibility = "hidden";
    vid.style.display = "none";
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("buttonLink");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

This is a perfect example of why good indentation is a must.

The scope where `myFunction` can be reached is `showErrorOnStart` contents, so anything outside `showErrorOnStart` can't access `myFunction`. You must define it outside:

```
function showErrorOnStart() {
    document.getElementById("video").innerHTML = "<p>This file is of unsupported type. Please download the file</p>";
    aud.style.visibility = "hidden";
    vid.style.display = "none";
}
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("buttonLink");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

With this it should work as expected (as long as where you define the function is the global scope, not inside another function).